How to diagnose Gradle issues in Flutter
I have a strange error where one of the plugins I used for a long time suddenly started to give Unresolved reference errors (either if called directly, or not found at all when the toolchain tries to instantiate it from GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java). Import statements are present and correct. The really challenging part is that the same app compiles all right if initiated from the command line (flutter.bat build appbundle ...) and only shows the error when built from the IDE, which is Android Studio.
I get the usual error:
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

But how can I get the log? I'm well aware of earlier similar questions but they don't work any more. Adding any of the options above to Settings > Build > Gradle-Android compiler > Command-line options has no influence. I do add -v to flutter run and the resulting output will be rather verbose, yes, but it shows everything before the error above in a verbose manner while it doesn't add any useful information to the actual error (apart from a stacktrace inside the compiler that is completely uninteresting here).
Using gradlew.bat --verbose, while working, doesn't interest me because, as I mentioned above, the error only appears when run from under the IDE, so a command line run will not help me.
I also tried GRADLE_OPTS or adding --debug directly into gradlew.bat in the line where it assembles the command but it doesn't change a thing in the output, or at least not anywhere that I can see it.
Versions for reference:

Flutter 3.24.0
Dart 3.5.0
Gradle 7.6
Android Studio 2024.1

Caches were cleared many times, including File > Invalidate Caches in AS and also manually during testing. The problem can be reproduced with the relevant plugin stored both in the usual Pub package cache and as a local copy.

Did you update Android Studio before it was working on your IDE? there might be configuration changes in your Android studio. you should see detailed logs of Android Studio and Gradle.

No. it happened practically out of the blue. I did change something but I'd hardly believe it has anything to do with it: I migrated my development drive to a SSD instead of a HDD. But before you're quick to point out that this must be the cause then :-), I have about a dozen or so other apps, all migrated correctly, every ENV var points to the appropriate location, more than triple checked by now, and this app also compiles from the command line. Still, of course, I don't rule out my error somewhere, that's why I would like to see the detailed log.

And, by the way, I wouldn't even say it coincides, the move was about a day earlier and I worked on the app in question after that. Without this error.

I see you have already tried lot of things. if you want to see log you can go to help menu at top.
Go to Help > Diagnostic Tools > Debug Log Settings...
Add #org.gradle.api to capture more detailed logs. After doing this, check the logs for any additional clues.
This might give android studio logs kind of I am not sure

If you spent this much time this might be some silly issue. can you try to run the project on some other machine if possible?

Not without installing AS, Flutter, Android SDK and everything else. :-) So I'll start with your previous suggestion first.

Unfortunately, nothing. It hands it off to flutter.bat but nothing else appears in the log.

It works again now but I wouldn't say I fixed it, so I'm a bit afraid of when it will come back. At any rate, some items of interest for anybody stumbling across the same problem:
In the end, there's a way to see the log. I said I had tried to modify gradlew.bat, among others. It finally worked but you have to add --debug, --verbose or --scan at the end, after %CMD_LINE_ARGS%. When I first tried, I put the extra switches after GRADLE_OPTS, as this was the place I found logical. It only works at the end. Also add the run argument -v in Edit Configurations and you'll get it. Actually, you get so much that it might overflow the Console's buffer.
So, when I added --scan, I got the log entries. But more than that, the project returned to normal, it compiled. And it compiles since then. And while I'm glad it does, I don't have the feeling that I fixed it...
